# Error: Can't resolve '@mat-datetimepicker/core/adapter' - I can't import a module

Tags: angular, typescript

I use the mat-datetimepicker that acts the same as the material datepicker, but add time to it too. I now try to change the format of the displayed datetime. For that I need to overwrite `MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS`.

My problem comes that I can't import `MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS`. How I try it:

```
import { MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS } from '@mat-datetimepicker/core/adapter';
```

And the error I get:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mat-datetimepicker/core/adapter'
```

If I look at my node_modules folder I find `MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS` under `@mat-datetimepicker/core/adapter`

[image]

It's in the file datetime-formats.d.ts.

You can also have a look at the repository at hithub:
https://github.com/kuhnroyal/mat-datetimepicker/tree/master/projects/core/src/adapter

But my Import does not work. 
What do I miss? Why can't it find the module?

Answer (score 0):

According to angular official documentation to change the date format you need to insert in app.module.ts exactly in provider your dateformat:

```
 providers: [
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT' }
]
```

Also remember to import LOCALE_ID in app.module.it

```
import {LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
```

after to to use MAT_DATE_FORMATS in your component add the provider:

```
Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` and `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` can be automatically provided by importing
    // `MatMomentDateModule` in your applications root module. We provide it at the component level
    // here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
  ],
})
```

with the follow imports:

```
import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

and you can play with the date like this:

```
startDate = moment([1970, 0, 1]);
  minDate = moment([1930, 0, 1]);
maxDate = moment([2004, 0, 1]);
```

Comment: I kinda want to do that, but with `MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS`, see also here: https://github.com/kuhnroyal/mat-datetimepicker#date-formatting, here comes the problem, I can't import MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS, the same is done in the official Material Datepicker: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats . So yea I need to do what you say, but not with `LOCALE_ID` but with `MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work! but it looks like you confuse `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` with MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS`. However I was trying different things again and import it directly from the core seems to work: `import { MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS } from '@mat-datetimepicker/core';` I just don't know why?.. `MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS` is in the subfolder adapter.. - I will prob. remove the question soon as it does not provide much for other people.

Comment: you can mark the question as self resolved, just write your solution

Comment: I did this, however I still cant tell why I am able to import it directly from the core, but not from the subfolder /adapter/.. So if you want to provide an answer with more infos, I will be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0):

`MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS` can be imported directly from the core:

```
import { MAT_DATETIME_FORMATS } from '@mat-datetimepicker/core';
```